# Format Intellij IDEA method parameter hints into Monospace?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to format [these hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdOti.png) to be Monospace? I'd like to do this to improve code readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override default fonts to achieve that.

[image]

As of November 2017 it is not possible to change font for parameter hints separately. Since this feature is only one year old and during its [release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/09/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-faster-git-log-parameter-hints-and-more/) was presented as follows

> This feature is still experimental and we appreciate your feedback on
>   it very much.

I believe you can request this functionality on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) or support existing issues ([1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174222), [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179444), [3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170292)).

Comment: This solves it, thanks and sorry for my (very) late answer.